# How to Separate a value from a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Column Populates with Debit and credit values like

```
100
150
-300
400
```

I created new column for `-300` as `CREDIT_ACCOUNT`. Since value is populating in that column. That Value should set to `null` in `DEBIT` COLUMN

Entire data is pulled and populated based on `Select` and `Case` statements. How to make sql WORK to SET `NULL` for `-300` in `DEBIT` COLUMN
That is populated based on

```sql
COALESCE
        (
        CASE DBO.TRUNC_NUM1((DBO.TO_NUMBER(DBO.TO_DATE(#prompt('Q_Date','string')#,'yyyy-mm-dd')-AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_DATE))/#prompt('P_Interval')#)
           WHEN 0 THEN 
                       CASE RTRIM(AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_REF)
                          WHEN 'BILL' THEN AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.REMAINING_AMOUNT
                       END
           ELSE NULL
        END 
        ,0) THIS_MONTH,       
        COALESCE
        (
        CASE DBO.TRUNC_NUM1((DBO.TO_NUMBER(DBO.TO_DATE(#prompt('Q_Date','string')#,'yyyy-mm-dd')-AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_DATE))/#prompt('P_Interval')#)
           WHEN 1 THEN 
                       CASE RTRIM(AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_REF)
                          WHEN 'BILL' THEN AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.REMAINING_AMOUNT
                       END
           ELSE NULL
        END 
        ,0) THIRTY,       
        COALESCE
        (
        CASE DBO.TRUNC_NUM1((DBO.TO_NUMBER(DBO.TO_DATE(#prompt('Q_Date','string')#,'yyyy-mm-dd')-AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_DATE))/#prompt('P_Interval')#)
           WHEN 2 THEN 
                       CASE RTRIM(AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_REF)
                          WHEN 'BILL' THEN AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.REMAINING_AMOUNT
                       END
           ELSE NULL
        END 
        ,0) SIXTY,
        COALESCE
        (
        CASE DBO.TRUNC_NUM1((DBO.TO_NUMBER(DBO.TO_DATE(#prompt('Q_Date','string')#,'yyyy-mm-dd')-AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_DATE))/#prompt('P_Interval')#)
           WHEN 3 THEN 
                       CASE RTRIM(AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_REF)
                          WHEN 'BILL' THEN AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.REMAINING_AMOUNT
                       END
           ELSE NULL
        END 
        ,0) NINETY,      
        DBO.TO_NUMBER
        (
        COALESCE
        (
        CASE DBO.TRUNC_NUM1((DBO.TO_NUMBER(DBO.TO_DATE(#prompt('Q_Date','string')#,'yyyy-mm-dd')-AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_DATE))/#prompt('P_Interval')#)
           WHEN 0 THEN NULL
           WHEN 1 THEN NULL
           WHEN 2 THEN NULL
           WHEN 3 THEN NULL
           ELSE 
                CASE RTRIM(AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.BILL_REF)
                   WHEN 'BILL' THEN AR_ACCOUNT_ITEM_NEW.REMAINING_AMOUNT
                END
        END 
        ,0)
        ) ONETWENTY,
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here Expected results **and** *your* attempt(s) will help us understand what you are trying to say here.

Comment: See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: Above (Part ) of whole query Popultes those value like 100,200,-300,400,500. -300 is credit amout and poplated into sepearte column called Credit statement . question is in the first column -300 should set to NULL because it belong to CREDIT COLUMN

Comment: Inother words above sub query is populating all values into one coulmn -- I need to set NULL for all credit amounts like -300, -250 ,-10 ETC . since they are populated new column called CREDIT _AMOUNT Throgh another CASE Statement

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the negative values to be in a different column, here is how:

```
Select Case When Debit_Amount >= 0 then Debit_Amount Else Null End as Debit_Amount,
    Case When Debit_Amount < 0 then Debit_Amount Else Null End as Credit_Amount, 
<Other Columns>
From
(
    -- Your Query to get Debit_Amount and other data
) Q
```

-- Or if your table is already populated:

```
Update YourTable 
Set Credit_Amount = Debit_Amount
Where Debit_Amount < 0

Update YourTable 
Set Debit_Amount = Null
Where Debit_Amount < 0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214467/discussion-on-answer-by-srinika-pinnaduwage-how-to-separate-a-value-from-a-colum).